# Join 2 Table with Android Kotlin Room and display plain data in a single Row in RecycleView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am experimenting with **Room**, **Live Data** and **Recycler View** in **Android Kotlin**.

My question is, I am trying to make an expense tracking APP, and I have 2 Table:

- one for the expense
- one for expense type

I **joined the table as indicated in Room documentation for 1:N relationship**.

Example of my table:

```
**Expense**
*ID = 1
expenseName = MyExpense1
expenseAmount = 100
expenseTypeID = 1*

**ExpenseType**
*ID= 1
ExpenseType= Home Expenses*

**Result expected from JOIN:**
*expenseName = MyExpense1
expenseAmount = 100
expenseType = Home Expenses*
```

But in this way, when I get the data for recycler view, I get a list that contain:

- Expense Type Class
- Expense list of Expense Class

How can I have data as if **I JOINED ** the table? Since my **ExpenseTypeWithExpense **class contains a class and a List of class

Usually I use a **RecycleView **on just one table and it is easy since I have a list of my Entity Class and I can access the single instance with list[position] in my **onBindViewHolder **class

## **EXPENSE Class**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys =[
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ExpenseType::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["expenseTypeID"]
        )]
)
data class Expense (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    val expenseName: String,
    val expenseAmount: Double,
    val expenseTypeID:Int
    )
```

## **EXPENSE TYPE Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense_type")
data class ExpenseType (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    val expenseType: String
    )
```

## **EXPENSE TYPE Join with EXPENSE Class (as per documentation of joining 1:n table)**

```
data class ExpenseTypeWithExpense (
    @Embedded val expenseType: ExpenseType,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn ="id",
        entityColumn ="id"
    )
    val expense: List<Expense>
    )
```

## **My DAO Interface**

```
@Dao
interface ExpenseDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertExpense(expense: Expense)

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertExpenseType(expenseType:ExpenseType)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM expense_type")
    fun getExpenseWithType():LiveData<List<ExpenseTypeWithExpense>>
}
```

## **Expense Repository**

```
class ExpenseRepository(private val expenseDao: ExpenseDao) {
    val readAllData: LiveData<List<ExpenseTypeWithExpense>> = expenseDao.getExpenseWithType()

    suspend fun insertExpense(expense: Expense){
        expenseDao.insertExpense(expense)
    }

    suspend fun insertExpenseType(expenseType: ExpenseType){
        expenseDao.insertExpenseType(expenseType)
    }
}
```

## **ExpenseViewModel**

```
class ExpenseViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val readAllData: LiveData<List<ExpenseTypeWithExpense>>
    private val repository: ExpenseRepository

    init {
        val expenseDao: ExpenseDao = ExpenseDatabase.getDatabase(application).expenseDao()
        repository = ExpenseRepository(expenseDao)
        readAllData = expenseDao.getExpenseWithType()
    }

    fun insertExpense(expense: Expense){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.insertExpense(expense)
        }
    }
    fun insertExpenseType(expenseType: ExpenseType){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.insertExpenseType(expenseType)
        }
    }

}
```

## **My Adapter**

```
class ListAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val expenseList = emptyList<ExpenseTypeWithExpense>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = expenseList[position]
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.expenseName).text =

# **       //currentItem is an instance of ExpenseTypeWithExpense and contains ExpenseType class and an Expense List**
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return expenseList.size
    }

}
```

## **       //currentItem is an instance of ExpenseTypeWithExpense and contains ExpenseType class and an Expense List** **

I do not Know how to handle this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `@Relation` there is no actual JOIN, rather for each parent (the @Embedded) the children are obtained as a list, as you have found.

If you want the true cartesian product then you would use a POJO without the @Relation  but rather `@Embeded` and the query would have the JOIN.

e.g.

```
data class ExpenseTypeWithExpense (
    @Embedded val expenseType: ExpenseType,
    @Embedded
    val expense: Expense
)
```

The query could then be:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expense_type JOIN expense ON expense_type.id = expense.expenseTypeID;")
```

**However**, as the **id** field is common to both and that rather than objects (ExpenseType and Expense being included in the output) You probably want the POJO to be

- When Room maps output columns to the fields, if there are any liked named columns the last is mapped.

:-

```
data class ExpenseTypeWithExpense (
    val idOfExpenseType:Int,
    val expenseType: String,
    val id:Int,
    val expenseName: String,
    val expenseAmount: Double,
    val expenseTypeID:Int
)
```

And the Query to (to rename the output columns so they can be assigned to the fields) as

```
@Query("SELECT expense_type.id AS idOfExpenseType, expense_type.expenseType, expense.* FROM expense_type JOIN expense ON expense_type.id = expense.expenseTypeID;;")
```

- as you can see the id column of the expense_type has been given a different name to map to the POJO. As * is not being used the expenseType has to be selected. However rather than specify all the columns of the expense table individually,expense.* is used to output all of the columns of the expense table.

If you had expense_type as:-

```
id  expenseType
1   T1
2   T2
3   T3
```

and expense as:-

```
id  expenseName expenseAmount   expenseTypeID
1   EXP1        100.11          1
2   EXP2        200.22          1
3   EXP3        300.33          1
4   EXP4        400.44          2
5   EXP5        500.55          2
```

Then the cartesian product output would be:-

[image]

which would equate to 5 ExpenseTypeWithExpense objects being returned in the LiveData<List>

Comment: I understand. Thank you @MikeT
So, if I use Relation, which for each parent return a List of child, I can't use a single RecycleView. Or I use 2 RecycleView, or I use a filter and show just Expense for 1 kind of ExpenseType

If I use the Embed and perfom a JOIN, I can display data in a single recycleView because data is returned as a cartesian product in a single List

Comment: @Stefano yes, although you could loop through parents and the children of the return of the `@Relation` and build the same. However, it would probably be more efficient to just let SQLite do all the work in one go.